Identify a movie about alien invasion
A few years ago, I watched a movie about alien invasion. Not much I remember about this movie because I only watch a little part of it. Here are what I know:

I watched it around 2-4 years ago.
It's in English and not animated.

This is about the scene a watch:

Alien invaded the Earth with giant mothership
Human fight back but not much they can do to the alien mothership
The alien ship sucks up forest, dirts and natural resources.
Human attempt to do suicide bombing (packed some soldier with bombs and make the soldiers get sucked by the alien ship)


Sounds like When Aliens Attack, a documentary, made by National Geographic, about an alien invasion scenario and how humans would react to it (National Geographic page of the film).
At the 0:55:19 mark in the film above there is a huge alien ship harvesting, at ca. 0:56 you can see the alien ship sucking up the trees, while humans are lurking in the forest below. At ca. 1:02:40 the alien mothership blows up and humans rejoice beneath the ship on the ground. At the 1:14:55 mark, 

some of the sick and dying turn their illness into a weapon, becoming
  biological suicide bombers.

At the 1:15:20 mark starts the sequence where sick people sacrifice themselves, they are being harvested by the alien ship.
1:22:40 mark: Soldiers armed with explosives ascend in balloons to blow up an alien mothership. At 1:27:30, an alien ship blows up.

I believe this is the one I looking for. Thank you

You are welcome.

Oblivion (2013) fits the description. It fits every bulletpoint except sucking up forest and dirt (they have hydrorigs and suck seawater). Alien is actually AI.

no, It's not Oblivion.
